# Correct use of COALESCE() in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, coalesce

I'm running the following script:

```sql
select COALESCE(test1,test2,test3)
from (select null as test1,'' as test2,'fdsda' as test3)
```

and receive the following error:

> No matching signature for function COALESCE for argument types: INT64,
>   STRING, STRING. Supported signature: COALESCE([ANY, ...]) at [1:8]

Any idea for the reason of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
select COALESCE(test1,test2,test3) from (select cast(null as string) as test1,'' as test2,'fdsda' as test3)
```

Anyway, I agree with rmesteves - different types in coalesce do not make sense.

Comment: Actually, it makes sense when you are just trying to make a merge query robust to null in keys and you generate the query without knowing the column type.
`merge ... on  coalesce(src.a,'_dummy_') = coalesce(tgt.a,'_dummy_')` is not possible (it is in some other SQL engines)

Answer (score 4):

When using `COALESCE`, you have to provide arguments of the same type.
For example, if the first argument is a STRING, the other ones should also be STRINGs.
In your case, you are trying to provide a INTEGER as the first parameter and STRINGs for the other ones.

Hope it helps

Comment: Good to know that NULL is an int type :)